# HTML/CSS/JavaScript LaTeX algorithm for word spacing

Tags: javascript, html, css, latex, spacing

I would like to know if there is a way to integrate the LaTeX word spacing algorithm in a website? I'm not talking about equations.

To better illustrate what I mean, look at thr picture. Above is a normal justify and below is a valuable word spacing with LaTeX.

[justify vs. LaTeX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY631.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, using JavaScript: https://github.com/bramstein/typeset

Whether you want to use it in production is a different question.